# PHP DOM XPath - Get child elements AND self (using query with contextnode)

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Using this XML for example...

```
<test>
  <tag0>
    <tag1 is="mine">
        <uselesstag>
            <tag3 is="mine">test</tag3>
        </uselesstag>
    </tag1>
    <tag2 is="mine">test2</tag2>
  </tag0>
</test>
```

... and getting an element for a contextnode (a contextnode is required)

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$context = $xpath->query("//tag1")->item(0);
```

... how can I get a nodelist containing any contextnode children **and including self contextnode** that attribute "is" is equal to "mine"? For example: I just want to get the tag1 and tag3 elements (tag1 is the contextnode)

```
$res = $xpath->query('.//*[@is="mine"]',$context);
```

In this case, only tag3 (child) is available on the nodelist.

```
$res = $xpath->query('..//*[@is="mine"]',$context);
```

In this case, tag1 (contextnode), tag3 (child) and tag2 (sibling) is available on the nodelist.

Answer (score 1):

XPath has a concept of axes. The default axis is `child`. An expression like `tag1` is actually the short form for `child::tag1`. `//tag1` is the short form for `/descendant::tag1`. Here are other axes, like `descendant-or-self`.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('descendant-or-self::*[@is="mine"]', $context) as $node) {
  var_dump($node->localName);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "tag1"
string(4) "tag3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $xpath->query('.//self::node()[@is="mine"]',$context);
```

This works!